# xUnit TestServer MVC CORE

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-core, xunit, fact

I am trying to setup a test for getting all my product but I am getting and `ArgumentNullException` but I do not get why, I recently started studying this so ...

This is the error message

> Message: System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: connectionString

```
private readonly TestServer server;
private readonly HttpClient client;

public ProductControllerIntegrationTests()
{
    server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseStartup<Startup>());
    client = server.CreateClient();
}

[Fact]
public async Task Product_Get_All()
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/Products");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Product>>(responseString);
    products.Count().Should().Be(12);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without the stack trace it's difficult to say. My best guess would be it's throwing the exception when you're instantiating your TestServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Message: System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: connectionString

For this error, it is caused by that you did not specific the Configuration when crating `TestServer`. In the product project, `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` in the `Program.cs` will configure **load Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration from 'appsettings.json'**.

If you want to test with production appsettings.json, you could try like below:

```
        public ProductControllerIntegrationTests()
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(configuration)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            );
        client = server.CreateClient();
    }
```

Comment: I have been banging my head for the past couple of days over this issue--this solution is simple and works like a champ!! Thanks!!